# Conditional on Multi Select for certain options only

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have a multiselect where I need to show/hide another select based on options selected in the first select. There are 3 options that should cause the other select to appear - all other options should not cause anything to change.

I have it working if individually the options are selected. However if one of the options is selected along with any other options it doesn't work.

DUE to CMS constraints I am unable to add classes to the options.

This is my current jQuery code.

```
$('#freeform_how_would_you_best_describe_your_companys_research_activity').change(function() {

            var selectedItems

            if ($(this).val() == 'Drug Discovery/Development' || $(this).val() == 'Therapeutics' || $(this).val() == 'Vaccines' ) {
                $('label[for="freeform_tell_us_more_about_your_research_activity"], select#freeform_tell_us_more_about_your_research_activity').slideDown();
            } else {
                $('label[for="freeform_tell_us_more_about_your_research_activity"], select#freeform_tell_us_more_about_your_research_activity').slideUp();
            }
        });
```

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Multiselect `.val()` returns *array* not a *single value*. Take it in account.

```js
$('#sel').change(function() {
  var arr = $(this).val();
  if (arr.indexOf('one') > -1 || arr.indexOf('two') > -1 || arr.indexOf('three') > -1) {
    console.log('do this');
  } else
    console.log('do that');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel" multiple size="5">
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>three</option>
  <option>else</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some additionaly googling and expermenting later I found a solution

```
        $('#freeform_how_would_you_best_describe_your_companys_research_activity').change(function() {

            var values = $(this).val();
            console.log(values)

            if(values.includes("Vaccines")|| values.includes("Therapeutics") || values.includes("Drug Discovery/Development")){
                $('label[for="freeform_tell_us_more_about_your_research_activity"], select#freeform_tell_us_more_about_your_research_activity').slideDown();
            } else {
               $('label[for="freeform_tell_us_more_about_your_research_activity"], select#freeform_tell_us_more_about_your_research_activity').slideUp();
            }
        });
```